# How to use Image inside Stack widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-image

I got an error when using Image inside Stack widget :

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
 ...
```

this is my code :

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                child: Flexible(
                  child: Image.asset(itemData["image"])
                ),
              ),
              const Positioned(
                 ...
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

of course, I defined my image assets in `pubspec.yaml` and I try to remove `flexible` widget also add `Row` layer above it, but it's still not working either...

this is my error when I remove `flexible` widget :

```
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/images/image2.jpg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:237:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:675:14)
<asynchronous suspension>

Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/image2.jpg")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#898db(), name:
"assets/images/image2.jpg", scale: 1.0)
```

So, How I can use (multiple) Images inside Stack Widget, and what's wrong with my code?
thank you for coming and I hope you have the solution. cheers

Comment: i am not getting any issues when i remove `Flexible` widget

Comment: failed to reproduce the error, try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: @nagendranag I was upload the error message in the question when I run without 'flexible' widget

Comment: try to wrap ClipRRect with Container then set heigh to 100 and weight to 100 and see if the image able able to display or not.

Comment: I think there is an issue with image assets.....if you add assets correctly then close your development environment and reopen it try again

Comment: Have u included your asset image directory in pubspec.yaml file for example flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/my_icon.png. For more info please refer to this link https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images

Comment: @TejaswiniDev yes, of course, I included my image directory in `pubspec.yaml` but still gives an error `Another exception was thrown: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.`

Comment: @DVCone remove the `Flexible` widget and try to re-check image assets related setup

Comment: @DVCone did you try close and reopening the dev environment

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
You have done everything perfect. but the one mistake was you wraped Image Widget by flexible. thats why flutter throws error. below code will work fine.

just remove flexible widget.

Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                        child: Image.network(
                          "https://www.writerswrite.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/how-long-to-read.png",
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        child: Container(
                          height: 20,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          width: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );

Flexible Widget used to adjust the available space near the widgets...
```

so renderobject not able to paint what you construct in UI because of you wraped flexible over Image

```
to learn more about flexible refer : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html

above code will working fine...
```

for image rendering issue : refer https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web-images

Comment: this does not work

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the Stack with expanded widget. I tried with the example below and it worked for me

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  child: Flexible(
                    child: Image.network(
                      "https://www.writerswrite.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/how-long-to-read.png",
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 20,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: asker getting issue related to image assets